# Configuring CraftCMS on Arcustech with Cloudflare flexible SSL returns 521 error

Tags: error, htaccess, ssl, cloudflare

I have installed CraftCMS on an Arcustech VPS and successfully added a domain name. Using the domain without the shared SSL works without any problems (e.g. www.example.com / example.com). However after adding the Cloudflare shared SSL certificate and using the "Flexible" configuration option, the website returns `Error 521 Web server is down`.

I have configured the domain in the CraftCMS CP to contain `https` and added the following to my `.htaccess` file:

```
# SSL only
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Am I missing a crucial step to get the SSL working?

Comment: Could be Cloudflare's proxy settings - check out this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329647/force-ssl-https-with-mod-rewrite/34065445#34065445)